# Mapping rules in XML to an input in perl

Tags: xml, regex, string, perl

I have an XML file in which few rules are defined as below:

```
<Rule id="1" author="xyz">
   <in>SN=${ID}</in>
   <out>SUN-${ID}</out>
</Rule>
<Rule id="2" author="xyz">
   <in>SN=${ID},MN=${mID}</in>
   <out>SUN-${ID}/MUN-${mID}</out>
</Rule>
```

I have an input  file where I will get my input as

```
SN=1,MN=RMMS2
```

I need to check this input against the rules in the xml file and should get the matching output through a perl script.

In this case I need to get output as

```
SUN-1/MUN-RMMS2
```

I am unable to match input against the Rules in XML file.

How can I compare the these two patterns?

Comment: What you are basically trying to do is implement an interpreter for a sort of programming language that you call "rules" and that comes in the form of an xml file. For that you will need at the very least know exactly what syntax that language is supposed to have. As in what rules may there be. Then you need to parse the xml file (preferably using some ready module from CPAN) to find all the "rules" stated there and then somehow decide which one to use and what to do. This is by no means a trivial task and SO is not a codewriting service. If you encounter a specific problem, come back and ask.

Comment: I've had success with this sort of thing by writing the rules in perl and eval-ing things. That way I didn't need to write an interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a regular expression from each `<in>` that will try to match the input. If the match is successful, you can use results of the match to transform the `<out>` to the expected output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml( location => 'rules.xml' );

my $input = 'SN=1,MN=RMMS2';

for my $rule ($xml->findnodes('//Rule')) {
    my ($pattern) = $rule->findvalue('in');
    $pattern =~ s/\${([^}]+)}/(?<$1>[^,]+)/g;
    if ($input =~ /^$pattern$/) {
        my %replace = %-;
        my $output = $rule->findvalue('out');
        $output =~ s/\${([^}]+)}/$replace{$1}[0]/g;
        print "$output\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what does my %replace = %-; mean?

Comment: @AnushaN: See `%-` in [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar).

Comment: @choroba Nice solution.  This has got to be the first time I've seen named back references as a useful construct.  :)  I created a slightly longer [alternative](https://eval.in/178848), but question is closed.

Comment: @Miller: I can vote for reopening it, but the question should be reworded before, probably.

Comment: @choroba Thanks mate, I'm not worried.  I honestly can't figure out how to edit the OP if I wanted to though.  It's not unclear to me, and obviously not to you either.